# Design a tuned common emitter amplifier

Tags: bjt

I'm getting stuck at the problem 2.16 in Art of Electronics.

"Design a tuned common emitter amplifier stage to operate at 100kHz. Use a bypassed emitter resistor, and set the quiescent current at 1mA. Assume Vcc is 15V, L = 1mH, and put a 6.2k resistor across LC to set Q = 10. Use capacitive input coupling."

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBEoGk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is this a correct design? I found two way to find C:

1) f = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(LC)) ( and I know f = 100kHz, L = 1mH)

2) Q = w0 RC ( Q is 10, R is 6.2k, and w is based on f = 100kHz)

And they give different results. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: You're missing the *bypassed* part of 'bypassed emitter resistor'...

Comment: Yes, I forgot that. But how do I solve the capacitor problem?

Comment: [Parallel RLC Circuit - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#Parallel_RLC_circuit) What more of an explanation did you need?

Comment: Your "different results" should not be very far apart. They can be accounted for by the fact that L = 1 mH and R = 6.2k are only approximately correct for 100 kHz and Q = 10. If L = 1 mH exactly, then R needs to be 6283 ohms (C = 2533 pF), and if R = 6200 exactly, then L needs to be 1.08 mH (C = 2341 pF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resistor needs to be 6.283K, then both methods will give you a value for C1 = 2,533 pf.  It is only a matter of doing the calculations with higher precision components.